# Adding Scrollview in Android Project Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, scrollview

I'm trying to let me layout scroll down. I've seen some posts with this, and I tried to do what they explained, but it didn't work for me. This is what I have now, and now my project won't even start, probably cause it's missplaced.

This is how my code looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />


     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.39"
        android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide contactgegevens."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
   </ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Scrollview has only one child, which can be a view group

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` can only has one child so you should add a `Layout Manager` that wrap all layout in `ScrollView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >
  ...
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        .../>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        .../>

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView> 
   ...
```

Comment: This entire code gives me the error: XML document must start and end with the same entity

Comment: @SneakyAndStuff did you close `LinearLayout` tag. make sure you open and close xml tag correctly

Comment: Did that, able to start application, still not able to scroll down.

Comment: did your textview long enough for scroll ?

Comment: Yes, I specially added text for that

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview has a only one child and your layuot having two child, use this spinets

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="276dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.39"
            android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide contactgegevens."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This entire code gives me the error: XML document must start and end with the same entity

Comment: at last add </LinearLayout>

Comment: in display we are not showing closing tag of LinearLayout, you should add </LinearLayout> below of </ScrollView>

Comment: Did that, able to start application, still not able to scroll down.

Comment: Its working, try to add some more textview inside linearlayout